# Apply If statement to strings within list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, conditional, mapthread

I think this a fairly basic question but I'm a relative newcomer to coding and would appreciate any help.

I have a list of lists. Within the lists there are a mixture of strings and numbers. I want to apply a rule to only the strings within the lists. My goal is to clean up the text and remove stuff like ''.

This is my list of lists:

```
data={{900, "WS", "PWS", "O", 3, "Watermaker 2 leaking", 
  "<div>Watermaker 2 was leaking at one of the fittings near the \
PRV.</div>", 1, "AHill", "02:00.0", "NULL", "NULL", "00:00.0", 
  "Ktaylor", "NULL", "<div>Straps replaced and leak fixed</div>", 
  "00:00.0", "00:00.0", 2, 0, 
  "<div>OEM design an specification.</div>", 182, "NULL", "NULL", 
  "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
  "Equipment in hazardous condition", ""}, {900, "WS", "PWS", "O", 2, 
  "No 1 and 2 RO Plant Feed Backwash Earth Straps Detached", 
  "<div>During visual inspection of the RO plants it was found that \
the earth connections on the feed backwash pumps on No1 &amp; No2 \
were detached. </div>", 1, "rmilne", "06:00.0", "NULL", "NULL", 
  "00:00.0", "rmilne", "NULL", "<div>Straps replaced.</div>", 
  "00:00.0", "00:00.0", 2, 0, 
  "<div>IEC 61140 : 1997 Protection against electric shock \[Dash] \
common aspects for installation and equipment. 5.1 Basic protection \
shall consist of one or more provisions that under normal conditions \
prevent contact with hazardous-live-parts</div>", 15, "NULL", "NULL", 
  "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "Electrical safety", ""}};
```

This is the code I tried to use:

```
MapThread[
 If[StringQ[#], 
   StringReplace[#, {"<", ">", "div", "/"} -> ""], #] &, data]
```

This returns this:

```
{900, "WS", "PWS", "O", 3, "Watermaker 2 leaking", "Watermaker 2 was \
leaking at one of the fittings near the PRV.", 1, "AHill", "02:00.0", \
"NULL", "NULL", "00:00.0", "Ktaylor", "NULL", "Straps replaced and \
leak fixed", "00:00.0", "00:00.0", 2, 0, "OEM design an \
specification.", 182, "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", \
"NULL", "Equipment in hazardous condition", ""}
```

This works well but only for the first list, the second list seems to be ignored. What do I need to add to apply to all lists?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map[ReplaceAll[ s_String :> StringTrim[s, "<div>" | "</div>"] ]] @ data
```

[image]

Alternatively, your code modified slightly:

```
Map[If[StringQ[#], 
   StringReplace[#, {"<", ">", "div", "/"} -> ""], #] &, data, 2]
```

> same result

Comment: That's great, much appreciated!